# HTML tags inside user defined function in JSP without using out.println

Tags: java, jsp

I have a method containing html tags and simple statements in JSP. I have made exclamation mark(!) before each statement. After deploying jsp in server, I checked jsp file and found that By doing this( using '!' sign ), My all statements remain in the same function and html goes in Service() method of jsp what is not desired at all. out.println() is an option for that but I donot want to use out.println() method for writing html beacuse it is equivalent to writing html in servlet.

JSP page after deployment:

```
public final class DynamicGUI
{
    // This is where the request comes in
     public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
     {
        JspWriter out = ...; 

    out.write("<html>");
    out.write("<head/>");
    out.write("<body>");
    out.write(printelements()); // i.e. write the results of the method call
    out.write("</body>");
    out.write("</html>");
}

// my method

private String printelements()
{
    // code stays here 
    but html tags goes into service(). I want them to be here
}
```

}

Is there any alternative to do same thing?

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you mean custom tag library?

Comment: I really donot have an idea regarding that. In that method, I have an recursion which keeps on printing textboxes. is it possible to do with custom tag library?

Comment: Yes you can. At least it works for me. I create tags in WEB-INF/ and put there my custom tag. It was possible to call one inside of same.

Comment: I will have to look at CTL. It is new for me. Thank you both

Comment: it is too lengthy bhesh. Tell me what exactly you need

Comment: and need is to place html <input> tags in the method, and not putting tags in method differently.